# Python MySQL connection. Running on a Virtual Machine

Tags: python, mysql, virtual-machine, mysql-python

I am trying to establish a connection to MySQL that is running locally using python.
i use the following code

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","username","password","dbname")
```

I am working on a virtual machine and I am running both the Python and MySQL on the VM. I am not able to make a connection.

I get this errror

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

I have tried providing the ip address of the VM in place of localhost and still didn't work. I tried specifying the port number too.
Is the connection different because it runs on a VM??

Comment: Are you able to connect to it using the `mysql` command line tool?

Comment: 10061 means `Connection Refused` make sure your mysql daemon/service is up

Comment: @VarinderSingh The MySQL service is running and I did verify that.

Comment: @Wooble I have not tried that. But do you think that would make any difference?

Comment: Well, if the command line tool also can't connect, it's almost certainly not a Python problem.

Comment: I get this error when I try using Command Prompt
Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect directly to mysql Database from command line does it work?

What OS is your VM running? If its a Unix then is there a mysqld process runnning?

In any case this may not have anything to do with Python. Your code snipppet looks ok. You just need to resolve the connectivity issue. Look at this page for details on how you could get to to the root of this problem.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I am running Windows Server 2008R2. I have tried that on the command prompt and that did not make any difference.

Comment: What do you mean by did not make any difference? Are you able to connect to your sql server database from command prompt using mysqld? Look at this  links to understand what we were suggesting... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client and mysql server on same machine as you said and mysql server is running you can try following

In your `my.cnf` which would be mostly in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in linux or check with your mysql installation on windows to find `my.cnf`

look for `bind-address` directive and set IP address to your VM host.If on linux you can see your VM ip using `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` on windows

you may also try commenting out `skip-networking` line if not already to allow remote clients

Restart mysqld

`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` on debian based distros, `service mysqld restart` for Redhat or restart mysql service on windows